# Today's Currency Exchange Rate in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to convert a value to NOK(USD to NOK for instance), but I have trouble getting the whole html page to load.

I am using the code found [here](http://investexcel.net/foreign-exchange-rate-function-in-excel/) , but the the html i get in return display this

```
    "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>USDNOK=X: Summary for USD/NOK- Yahoo! Finance</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><met
```

So it is basically stripping the webpage, or rather is not waiting untill its done loading. The code in the link for getting webpage is this:

```
Function ExecuteWebRequest(ByVal url As String) As String


Dim oXHTTP As Object

If InStr(1, url, "?", 1) <> 0 Then
    url = url & "&cb=" & Timer() * 100
Else
    url = url & "?cb=" & Timer() * 100
End If

Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
oXHTTP.send
ExecuteWebRequest = oXHTTP.responseText
Set oXHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

Maybe there is a better way of getting todays exchange rate in vba.

Comment: The chunk of data you are seeing is around 250 bytes, which suggests that there a 255/256-byte limit might be in there somewhere. The VBA looks OK to me, so I wondered how you were displaying the data and whether for example you are using an EXCEL spreadsheet function that would truncate it, and whether you were doing that because you got an error in one of the mid() calls - the code worked here, except that the version posted on the web page you linked to is incorrect. The version in the spreadsheet uses instr to look for an HTML (td) end tag, but the web page version is looking for ""

Comment: BTW, AFAICS although the code does appear to work, I think it should probably be looking for a particular node in the HTML document and getting its value, rather than using instr and mid to do the same thing. But I'm not going to attempt to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

This [code](https://desmondoshiwambo.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/how-to-get-the-current-exchange-rateconvert-currency-in-access-excel-and-vba-using-yahoo-finance/) works superb, it uses Yahoo as well, but is up to date with html parsing.